# To Access the values of a datagrid from User control to an aspx page

Tags: asp.net, datagrid, user-controls

I have an application, in which on an aspx form I am loading a web user control at runtime based on the selected input. This user control contains a datagrid, which is populated on page_init of the ascx file.

Now the problem is upon editing I am unable to save the data, the save button which is there on the user control doesn't fire, and as a result I am trying to access the gridview on my aspx page to save the values.

I tried using the property, session everything possible but no luck.

Can anyone please explain how to achieve this? With example please.